# Is there a sensible way to extract the least significant digits from a bitset?

Tags: c++, stl, bitset

I have a bitset of size 81 so it doesn't fit into any primitive c++ type. I need to access 9 bit contiguous subsets from the bitset and imagined that I could just shift the big set and call .to_ulong() to extract them. It seems that the STL wants to be safe and just gives me an overflow_error when I try.

```
int offset = something_that_is < 81;
bitset<81> set;
int subset = ((set >> offset).to_ulong()) & 511;
```

This snippet, although mathematically perfectly safe, throws an exception. Can I force it got give me the least significant ulong somehow or would I need to extract the bits using the [] operator?

I noticed that there is a underlying implementation consisting of an array but all members that refer to it seem to be private.

while the previous code doesn't work, this one does.

```
int offset = something_that_is < 81;
bitset<81> set;
int subset = ((set >> offset) & 511).to_ulong();
```

Although that should probably have been an unsigned long instead of an int.

Comment: Although it's ok in your example, I wouldn't name a variable `set`.  It would be confusing since there is already a `std::set` type.

Comment: Does it help if you do `&511` before `to_ulong()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closer to what I think you want:

```
std::bitset<81> bs;
const std::bitset<81> nineset = 0x1ff;
int number_of_sets = 81 / 9;

for (int x = 0; x < number_of_sets; x++)
{
    std::bitset<81> tmp = bs;
    tmp &= nineset;
    unsigned long value = tmp.to_ulong(); // this is your value

    // prep for the next set
    bs >>= 9;
}
```

Comment: May I spent a [**live demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18b2df6ae55f6cb6)?